# GDAL virtual file system, how to create your own

Tags: gdal

I just found a blob post about, [GDAL virtual file system](http://erouault.blogspot.dk/2012/05/new-gdal-virtual-file-system-to-read.html), and I was wondering if I could create my own and how to do so?

I want to create a virtual file system for reading directly from blob storage. So any example with virtual file system, i think I can managed to learn and create my own.

Do anyone have examples. (its microsoft azure I am going to create for, maybe someone already created one for aws s3)

Comment: I think you should better ask on the GDAL-dev mailing list http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev and also see this discussion for S3 http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2014-August/039897.html

Comment: There are VSI implementations that can use memory buffers and 'subfiles' (files within files).  See:

http://gdal.org/cpl__vsi_8h.html#af9c1b931449d423e7a80bacb75ff0717

and 

http://gdal.org/cpl__vsi_8h.html#abaee4232440e012b4b9920934fc571cc

Comment: I want to create my own and not use the memory buffer one. The reason is that, I can do random access to files on azure blob storage by http. Goal is that I dont want to download 1GB files for those tools that dont need to, like gdalinfo. So if i could make a virtual file system that gave access to remote storage like normal filesystem.

Comment: You can probably use the /vsicurl/ handler.  If not, it would be a perfect example for you.

Comment: I guess, /vsicurl/ would also download the whole file. Where is the source code for it and I can modify it i guess

Comment: It depends on what you are asking for and the driver.  gdalinfo /vsicurl/... will download what the driver needs to display the info.  If you pass -stats, it would have to donwload the image data.

Comment: Thanks. The vsicurl thing worked out very nicely, it didnt download the whole thing